# A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: 0, of entity: AppCrashLogData - NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate in my web Api. When I try to insert values to oracle database using NHibernate I am getting this exception. I have SEQNO column which is incremented using trigger and a sequence, when row is inserted to the table. So I don't want to insert it from front end. I pass everything but SEQNO and APITIME from front end.

**Method**

```
  using (ISession session = OpenSession())
    {

        ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {

            foreach (AppCrashLogData ss in list)
            {

                ss.APITIME = DateTime.Now;
                session.Evict(ss);
                session.Save(ss);                  

            }

            transaction.Commit();
            transaction.Dispose();
            session.Close();
            result = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            result = false;
        }

    }
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="CustomerAppWS"  namespace="CustomerAppWS.Models">
  <class name="AppCrashLogData" table="SLIC_NET_LIFE.CUSS_APP_CRASH_LOG" lazy="true" >

    <id name="SEQNO" column="SEQNO" generator="assigned" unsaved-value="0" />
    
    <property name="USERNAME">
      <column name="USERNAME" sql-type="VARCHAR2"  not-null="false" />
    </property>

    <property name="EXHEAD">
      <column name="EXHEAD" sql-type="VARCHAR2"  not-null="false" />
    </property>

    <property name="EXDETAIL">
      <column name="EXDETAIL" sql-type="VARCHAR2"  not-null="false" />
    </property>

    <property name="APPTIME">
      <column name="APPTIME" sql-type="DATETIME"  not-null="false" />
    </property>

    <property name="APITIME">
      <column name="APITIME" sql-type="DATETIME"  not-null="false" />
    </property>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**AppCrashLogData**

```
public class AppCrashLogData
{
    public virtual int SEQNO { get; set; }
    public virtual string USERNAME { get; set; }
    public virtual string EXHEAD { get; set; }
    public virtual string EXDETAIL { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime APPTIME { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime APITIME { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nH knows how to insert records whose ID is driven by a sequence. The XML would look something like:

```
    <id name="SEQNO" column="SEQNO">
        <generator class="sequence-identity">
            <param name="sequence">NAME_OF_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
```

It should make nH generate the required `INSERT .. sequence.nextval RETURNING ... INTO ...` query

If you want to keep the trigger based method you can declare the generator to be of class "trigger-identity" to make nH generate a similar insert that retrieves values calc'd by a "before insert" trigger

Comment: thanks. I will go with *trigger-identity*